# How create splitmenu in Firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

How create splitmenu in Firefox addon?
I make this:

```
var itemx = window.document.createElement('splitmenu');
itemx.setAttribute("style", '-moz-binding: url("chrome://browser/content/urlbarBindings.xml#splitmenu")'); window.document.getElementById("contentAreaContextMenu").appendChild(itemx);
```

It does not look good. I can not find documentation.

Such an effect of your code:

[image]

Anonymous missing elements?
[image]

Comment: I get the same result you got on Firefox 29, but for Firefox 28 and below it works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it turned out that mor bindings are required, so either link to 'browser.css' or copy the bindings from it:

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

splitmenu {
  -moz-binding: url("chrome://browser/content/urlbarBindings.xml#splitmenu");
}

.splitmenu-menuitem {
  -moz-binding: url("chrome://global/content/bindings/menu.xml#menuitem");
  list-style-image: inherit;
  -moz-image-region: inherit;
}

.splitmenu-menuitem[iconic="true"] {
  -moz-binding: url("chrome://global/content/bindings/menu.xml#menuitem-iconic");
}

.splitmenu-menu > .menu-text,
:-moz-any(.splitmenu-menu, .splitmenu-menuitem) > .menu-accel-container,
#appmenu-editmenu > .menu-text,
#appmenu-editmenu > .menu-accel-container {
  display: none;
}
```

it seems up to Firefox 28, `browser.css` is referenced but not in newer versions....

it would be messy to test using js code, so i tested using a xul window:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/global.css"?>
<!--<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://browser/content/browser.css" type="text/css"?>-->

<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://mdsy_test/content/splitmenu/binding.css"?>

<window xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
        persist="screenX screenY width height">


<menubar>
    <menu id="file-menu" label="File" accesskey="F">
        <menupopup id="menu_FilePopup">
            <menuitem id="menu_newNavigatorTab" label="New Tab" command="cmd_newNavigatorTab" key="key_newNavigatorTab" accesskey="T"/>
            <menuseparator/>

            <splitmenu label="cool" oncommand="alert('SPLIT')">
                <menupopup>
                    <menuitem label="menu item!" oncommand="alert('ITEM')"/>
                </menupopup>
            </splitmenu>

        </menupopup>
    </menu>
</menubar>

</window>
```

i tested on Firefox 16, 28, and 29

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var itemx = window.document.createElement('splitmenu');
itemx.setAttribute("style", '-moz-binding: url("chrome://browser/content/urlbarBindings.xml#splitmenu")');
itemx.setAttribute("label", "cool");

var pop = window.document.createElement('menupopup');
itemx.appendChild(pop);

var m = window.document.createElement('menuitem');
m.setAttribute("label", "menu item!");
pop.appendChild(m);


window.document.getElementById("contentAreaContextMenu").appendChild(itemx);
```

Comment: The effect of the topic.